# How to use Outlook Scheduling Assistant to generate a list of available meeting times between all required parties?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, scheduling

I am on a project whereby the specific time of the meeting is less important than finding a time we can all meet. Thus, I'd like to have a method whereby I can have Scheduling Assistant suggest all the times we can meet for an hour between x day and y day. To clarify, let's say John is free 9-11am on MWF, and Jane is free 9-11am on WF. I don't care if I'm meeting at 9 or 10, just that I get a 1 hour meeting with them on either Wednesday or Friday. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to see the Free/Busy status displayed by the scheduling assistant in a period of time?

If so, as I know, we can change the days displayed by adjusting the percentage as shown in the below figure.

[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Comment: Ty for your answer. I think this is what I am looking for.